# How do we change customer email programmatically in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, email, customer-account

How do we change a customer's email programatically in Magento 2?

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue

Answer (score 3):

**Use `\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface` to change customer information.**

```
protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;

public function __construct ( 
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    ...
}

public function changeCustomerInfo()
{
    $customerId = '1'; // customer ID
    $customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
    $customer->setEmail("email@domain.com");  //set customer email
    $customer->setFirstname("First Name"); //set customer First Name
    $customer->setLastname("Last name"); // set customer Last Name
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->save($customer);
}
```